# Swift error: missing argument label 'name:' in call

Tags: swift

I'm learning about default arguments and I ran aground of something weird:

```
import UIKit

func greet(name: String = "world") {
    println("hello \(name)")
}

greet("jiaaro")
```

this throws an error:

> ```
> Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:9:7: error: missing argument label 'name:' in call
> greet("jiaaro")
>       ^
>       name:
> ```

I understand that it wants `greet(name: "jiaaro")` but I *don't* understand why that should be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift : missing argument label 'xxx' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050844/swift-missing-argument-label-xxx-in-call)

Comment: @jtbandes this question is older, and I posted a link to it (in the comments) on the question you linked when that question was first asked (6 minutes after to be precise ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swift functions can specify local and external argument names:

```
func greet(who name: String = "world") {
    println("hello \(name)")
}

// prints "hello world"
greet()

// prints "hello jiaaro"
greet(who:"jiaaro")

// error
greet("jiaaro")

// error
greet(name: "jiaaro")
```

To opt out of this behavior you can use an underscore for the external name. Note that the first parameter implicitly uses the "no external name" behavior:

```
func greet(name: String = "world", _ hello: String = "hello") {
    println("\(hello) \(name)")
}

// prints "hello world"
greet()

// prints "hello jiaaro"
greet("jiaaro")

// prints "hi jiaaro"
greet("jiaaro", "hi")

// error
greet(name: "jiaaro")
```

> The following is now disallowed in Swift 2.0, see below for equivalent code.

You can use the `#` prefix to use the same local and external name for the first parameter:

```
func greet(#name: String = "world", hello: String = "hello") {
    println("\(hello) \(name)")
}

// prints "hi jiaaro"
greet(name: "jiaaro", hello: "hi")
```

> Swift 2.0 code:
>
> ```
> func greet(name name: String = "world", hello: String = "hello") {
>     println("\(hello) \(name)")
> }
>
> // prints "hi jiaaro"
> greet(name: "jiaaro", hello: "hi")
> ```

Comment: what's the difference between these two lines? // prints "hello jiaaro"
greet("jiaaro")

// error
greet("jiaaro")

Comment: @SamBudda Oops… copy/paste error - I had to keep retyping this stuff because the playground was crashing on me. Overlooked that on the 3rd or 4th time re-making the example :)

Comment: XCode 6.1 no longer requires a name label for the first argument. In fact you get a warning if you use a label: Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'name' has no keyword argument name

Comment: @MikeLischke ok, thanks. So methods and functions now have the same behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Swift requires argument labels by default, because it supports classes with multiple initializers. The benefit of argument labels comes from the ability of Swift to infer which initializer to use; not only by argument type, but argument name as well.

```
struct Celsius {
    var temperatureInCelsius: Double = 0.0

    init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }

    init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
    }
}

let boilingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
// boilingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 100.0

let freezingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromKelvin: 273.15)
// freezingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 0.0
```

See this page for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_272

Comment: And for better objective C compatibility ;)

Comment: That too, I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that now your code

```
func greet(name: String = "world") {
    print("hello \(name)")
}

greet("jiaaro")
```

works fine in xcode, i just changed "println" with "print"