# Forced to use parameter names, but only some of them

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I've read the [Swift Function Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) and as far as I understand a function has to be built this way:

```
func funcName(param1:Type, param2:Type) -> Return {
    //Whatever istructions
}
```

And has to be called this way:

```
funcName(1, 2);
```

Very easy, and here is from the original Apple documentation:

```
func halfOpenRangeLength(start: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
    return end - start
}

println(halfOpenRangeLength(1, 10))
// prints "9"
```

So in this last example when calling the `halfOpenRangeLength` function I don't have to specify the name of the parameters (`start` and `end`).

So I did my function in XCode:

```
func assegnaRisposte(uno:String, due:String, tre:String, quattro:String){
    button1.setTitle(uno, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button2.setTitle(due, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button3.setTitle(tre, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button4.setTitle(quattro, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

But when I call it this way I get the error `Missing argument lables 'due:tre:quattro:' in call`:

```
assegnaRisposte("Davide", "Andrea", "Sergio", "Roberto")
```

And the XCode fix imposes me to do it this way:

```
assegnaRisposte("Davide", due: tre: "Andrea", "Sergio", quattro: "Roberto")
```

So I'M FORCED to place 3 of the parameter names. If I place the first parameter (uno) it throws an error, so I have to put ONLY `due`, `tre` and `quattro`

As far as I read I can specify the parameter names placing a dash in front of the parameter, and also, I'm not FORCED to use them.

Can somebody explain me why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between functions and methods in Swift in naming, basically:

- the default naming of **functions** is that there are no external
  parameter names.
- the default naming for **methods** is that there are    external
  parameter names expect the first parameter.

And you can read about the differences between methods and functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136184/2592349) or [here](http://danielnagy.hu/?p=21).

**Updated:**

If you don't want to use external parameter names, you should declare your **method** like:

```
func assegnaRisposte(uno:String, _ due:String, _ tre:String, _ quattro:String){
...
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and give me some more data so that I can understand what you mean and how to fix my code? I don't need the argument labels.

Comment: well, you can read about that here: http://danielnagy.hu/?p=21

Comment: but if you don't want to use external parameter names, declare your method like: func assegnaRisposte(uno:String, _ due:String, _ tre:String, _ quattro:String)

Comment: Gr8! This last comment should be in the answer I think. :D Tks a lot

Comment: @Mr.Web welcome! I updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section from Apple's The Swift Programming Language book:

> [Local and External Parameter Names for Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)
>
> The default behavior of local names and external names is different
>   for functions and methods.
>
> Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter
>   name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names
>   both local and external parameter names by default.