# What's the _ underscore representative of in Swift References?

Tags: objective-c, function, swift, declaration

In the reference section of Apple's docs there's lots of instances of this sort of thing:

> `func runAction(_`*`action`*`: SKAction!)`

The Objective-C 'equivalent' of this is:

> `- (void)runAction:(SKAction *)`*`action`*

It strikes me that it's probably important that (in the Swift reference) there's a space after the underscore and "action" is written in italics.

But I can't figure out what this is trying to convey. So perhaps the question is... is there a reference for the conventions used in the references?

-- here's the page I'm referencing in this reference to the underscore use:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction

### Update

Swift 3 has made some changes to how function/method parameter names and argument labels are used and named. This has ramifications on this question and its answer. @Rickster does an amazing job of answering a different question about _underscores in functions that clears much of this up, here: [Why do I need underscores in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627106/why-do-i-need-underscores-in-swift)

Comment: The documentation is following the mathematical convention of using italics for variable names.  For example: sin² *a* + cos² *a* = 1.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Both answers were correct but I want to clarify a little bit more.

`_` is used to [modify external parameter name behavior for methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID237).

In [Local and External Parameter Names for Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID236) section of the documentation, it says:

> Swift gives the first parameter name in a **method** a local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names **both local and external parameter names** by default.

On the other hand, functions by default don't have external parameter names.

For example, we have this `foo()` method defined in class `Bar`:

```
class Bar{
    func foo(s1: String, s2: String) -> String {
        return s1 + s2;
    }
}
```

When you call `foo()`, it is called like `bar.foo("Hello", s2: "World")`.

**But**, you can override this behavior by using `_` in front of `s2` where it's declared.

```
func foo(s1: String, _ s2: String) -> String{
    return s1 + s2;
}
```

Then, when you call `foo`, it could be simply called like `bar.foo("Hello", "World")` without the name of the second parameter.

Back to your case, `runAction` is a method because it's associated with type `SKNode`, obviously. Thus, putting a `_` before parameter `action` allows you to call `runAction` without an external name.

**Update for Swift 2.0**

Function and method now work **the same way** in terms of local and external argument name declaration.

Functions are now called by using external parameter name by default, starting at 2nd parameter. This rule only applies to pure Swift code.

So, by providing an `_` in front of a **function**, the caller won't have to specify external parameter name, just like what you would do for a **method**.

Comment: Confused, if the `_` write before the second parameter, your answer is clearly enough; what if in `func runAction(_action: SKAction!)` , the `_` is before the first parameter or if you write the following code        `func foo(_ s1: String) {
    // your code
}` Xcode would give you a warning, but there's a lot code like `func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView)`in the reference,why?

Comment: so basically, it does this for no reason and just confuses everybody. awesome.

Comment: @Wyatt Zhang, the doc says, that usage of `_` for the first parameter is extraneous. I can make an assumption, that the designers think it's obviously enough for your code and doesn't enchance readability, quite the contrary, it soils the code. So you get the warning. The reference has the opposite goal: it has to be as clear as it's possible - so the first parameter's underscore is mentioned for EVERY method. That would explain everything)

Comment: It's important to note that Swift 3.0 changes things. All labels are required, unless you specify otherwise. So the `-` before the first parameter is no longer extraneous. For example: `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` signals that the caller (Objective-C code) won't be using a parameter label

Comment: This answer should be updated and/or significantly rewritten to reflect the newer Swift terminology specified within [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166)

Answer (score 84):

The underscore is a general token used to indicate a discarded value.

In this specific case, it means that the function will be invoked as `runAction(argument)` instead of `runAction(action:argument)`

In other contexts it has other similar meaning, e.g. in:

```
for _ in 0..<5 { ... }
```

It means that we merely want to execute the block 5 times and we don't care about the index within the block.

In this context:

```
let (result, _) = someFunctionThatReturnsATuple()
```

It means that we don't care what the second element of the tuple is, only the first.

Comment: So in this case the argument (an action) is an option?

Comment: No, it causes the external parameter name (action:) in this case, to be empty, thus omitted.  The argument is still required, it's just not tagged with action:.

Comment: The real answer is a combination of @dasblinkenlight's answer and mine.  He addresses this specific case more precisely, whereas mine addresses the broader question, what does _ mean?

Comment: You can use the discard sign also for very big numbers to make them more readable like this `let pi = 3.141_592_653_59`

Comment: amusingly, you can also use it to make very big numbers less readable, like `let pi = 3.1_4_15_92___63`

Comment: While this is all factual information, this does not answer the question and will only serve to confuse future viewers.

Answer (score 19):

**Since Swift 3** all argument labels are required by **default**.

You can force an IDE to hide an argument label with `_`.

```
func foo(a: String) {
}
    
func foo2(_ a: String) {
}
```

called `foo(a: "abc")` and `foo2("abc")`

> **Note:** This can be used only when `a` is the *(external) argument label* and *(internal) variable name* at the same time. It's equivalent - `func foo(a a: String)` won't accept the `_`.

### Why is Apple using it?

You can see Apple is using it across the API. Apple's libraries are still written in Objective-C *(if not, they share the same function names anyway, which were designed for Objective-C syntax)*

Functions like `applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` would have **redundant** parameter name `application`, since there is already the *application* in it's function name.

### Your example

`func runAction(_ action: SKAction!)` would be called **without** its `_` mark like `runAction(action:)`.
The parameter name `action` would be **redundant** since there is already one in the function name. That's the purpose and why it's there.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and should have far more attention than it's gotten.

Answer (score 13):

An identifier in front of parameter declaration defines an *external* parameter name. This is the name that must be provided by the caller when calling the function:

```
func someFunction(externalParameterName localParameterName: Int)
```

Swift provides an automatic external name for any defaulted parameter you define, if you do not provide an external name yourself. Using an underscore for the external parameter name opts out from this behavior:

> You can opt out of this behavior by writing an underscore (`_`) instead of an explicit external name when you define the parameter.

You can read more about this behavior in the section on *External Names for Parameters with Default Values* [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Comment: so... let me see if my dimwittedness has got this right. In this example I should name my parameter variable/constant as "action" and assign it to the SKAction that I want run by this function, and Swift automatically names the required default parameter "action". HOWEVER, if I want to custom name this action I must use the underscore in the calling of the function?

Comment: @Confused My understanding is that `SK`'s designers don't want you to write `action` twice, because "action" is already a part of the function's name. In other words, they don't want you to write `sprite.runAction(action:moveGroundSpritesForever)`. The purpose of external parameter names was to make your code "read like a sentence"; using `action` twice would defeat the purpose of that.

Comment: Some lights went on in the darkness. I think I get it. This feature of the language is intended to make calling functions in Swift look a lot like how you'd call a method with parameters in Objective-C. Maybe.

Comment: However the underscore can be used to somehow opt out of having these external parameter names for parameters defined with a default value... just haven't seen how that's done, yet. Will keep looking.

Comment: So... in short, it simply switches between named parameters and ordinal parameters, so you can easily toggle between

`foo.bar(param: 'fiddle')`

and

`foo.bar('fiddle')`

NOTE: with only one argument it really doesn't become apparent... but with multiple arguments it becomes very relevant:

`foo.bar(param1: 'fiddle', param2: 'dee')`

vs

`foo.bar('fiddle','dee')`

Answer (score 10):

I think this forces a convention in Swift that makes it read closer to objective-c, which matches cocoa conventions better. In objc you don't (externally) name your first parameter. Instead, by convention you usually include the external name in the latter part of the method name like this:

```
- (void)myFancyMethodWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName;

[someInstance myFancyMethodWithFirstName:@"John" lastName:@"Doe"];
```

To make Swift api calls consistent with objc you will want to suppress the external parameter name of the first param.

```
func myFancyMethodWithFirstName(_ firstName:String, lastName:String);

someInstance.myFancyMethodWithFirstName("John", lastName:"Doe")
```

Comment: I like this explanation. having learned Obj-C first, you've cleared things up. It also highlights the importance of naming the Method appropriately in Swift, namely, the latter part of the Method name should describe the first argument, as is typically the case in Obj-C. good stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a difference between the real code used to define a method and the method declaration in Apple's docs. Let's take **UIControl**'s 
*- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:* method for example, the real code is:
 [image]

But in docs, it appear like this (notice _ before target):
[image]

In real code, _ is used to make the second or subsequent parameter's external name
not appear when a method is called, while **in docs, _ before a parameter's local name indicates that when you call a method or a function, you should not provide an external name.**

There's no external name when a function is called by default unless you provide your own or add # before (without whitespace) a parameter's local name, for example, this is how we use *dispatch_after*:
[image]

And in docs, it appear like this (notice three _):
[image]

The convention of function's declaration is just the same as I have described for method.

Answer (score 1):

Just more visually.

[image]

As you can see the `_` just make omit a local parameter name or not.