# ReactNative native-modules Promise passing field and in Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native, promise, native-module

I'm trying to run a promise in React Native using Swift and passing one field (array). 
This is the code that i have:

GuidedTourInterfaceBridge.m

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(GuidedTourInterface, NSObject)

   RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(readFile(_ arr: NSArray, resolver: RCTPromiseResolveBlock resolve, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock reject))
@end
```

GuidedTourInterface.swift:

```
...
@objc
func readFile(_ arr: NSArray, resolver resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    ...
    resolve(["success" : true, "base64Content" : base64Content ])
}
...
```

JS File:

```
...
readFileInfoJson = async () => {
  try {

      var result = await guidedTourInterface.readFile([this.props.mapToShow+"/info.json"]);
      ...
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
 }
```

The error message I am receiving:

> guidedTourInterface.readFile is not a function. (In
>   'guidedTourInterface.readFile([_this.props.mapToShow+"/info.json"])',
>   'guidedTourInterface.readFile' is undefined)]

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this or what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason for the underscore in `_ arr`?

Comment: @TaylorKline have look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876068/what-is-in-swift-telling-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get resolve the problem. Here is the solution for anyone who might need

GuidedTourInterfaceBridge.m

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(readFile:(NSArray *)arr resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock *)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock *)reject)
```

GuidedTourInterface.swift:

```
  func readFile(_ arr: NSArray, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
```

JS File:

```
var result = await guidedTourInterface.readFile([this.props.mapToShow+"/info.json"])
          .then((result) => {
```