# What do _:_: and similar combinations of the colon and underscore mean in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

When reading Swift's documentation, Apple commonly uses `functionName(_:name:)` or something similar. What exactly is this pattern that sometimes is `_:_:`, sometimes just `_:`, and `_:name:`. I think it has to do with parameter shorthand, but I'm not sure, and can't find the explanation in Swift's programming guide. Thank you!

Example:

```
insert(_:atIndex:)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The underscore indicates that there is no external parameter name for the function. [Apple's Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) talks about this concept in terms of when you're writing your own functions.

Take the case where you write this function (from the documentation):

```
func sayHello(to person: String, and anotherPerson: String) -> String { ... }
```

If you were to use the function you would write the following:

```
sayHello(to: "Bill", and: "Ted")
```

The signature for this would be `sayHello(to:and:)`.
However, what if we wanted to use the function as `sayHello("Bill", "Ted")`? How would we indicate that we didn't want an external parameter name? Well that's where the underscore comes in. We could rewrite the function as:

```
func sayHello(person: String, _ anotherPerson: String) -> String { ... }
```

Note the first parameter doesn't need the _, but subsequent ones will. The first is inferred to have no parameter name. This makes the method signature for this call `sayHello(_:_:)` because you as the caller don't have a named parameter.

**Update Swift 3.0:**

Swift 3.0 treats all parameters equally. The first parameter now requires an underscore to indicate the absense of an external parameter name. In the above example of having `sayHello("Bill", "Ted")` at the call site, your corresponding function or method declaration would have to be

```
func sayHello(_ person: String, _ anotherPerson: String) -> String { ... }
```

Note the addition of the underscore before the internal parameter name 'person'.

Comment: How is your last definition different than `func sayHello(person: String, anotherPerson: String) -> String { ... }` ?

Comment: @7stud As of Swift 1.2, it depends if you're making a function or a method. If you make a standalone function, it isn't any different. However, if you declare this inside of a class (making it a method), it will assume that the second parameter (and subsequent parameters) with only the internal name also serve as the external name. Basically, if `func sayHello(person: String, anotherPerson: String) -> String` is written as a function, it becomes `sayHello(_:_:)`. In a class as a method it becomes `sayHello(_:anotherPerson:)`. I think Swift 2 made a change to this though.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm adding an answer and quoting the docs to explain that "feature".

Comment: @7stud I'm pretty sure this has been changed though in Swift 2 so that function syntax works the same way as method syntax. Just fyi.

Comment: Okay.  Then for swift version 1.2 people the explanation is in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore indicates an ignored value. You can read more about it here:
[What's the _ underscore representative of in Swift References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437388/whats-the-underscore-representative-of-in-swift-references)

In the documentation it is being used as a wildcard to indicate a function that takes an unnamed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

share my learning experience.

```
//MARK: Default
func join1(s1: String, s2: String, joiner: String) -> String {
    println("join1" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}

//MARK: External Parameter Names
// To make the purpose of these String values clearer, define external parameter names for each join function parameter
func join2(string s1: String, toString s2: String, withJoiner joiner: String) -> String {
    println("join2" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}

//MARK: External Names for Parameters with Default Values
func join3(string s1: String, toString s2: String, withJoiner joiner: String = " ") -> String {
    println("join3" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}

//MARK: No External Names for Parameters with Default Values
func join4(s1: String, s2: String, joiner: String = " ") -> String {
    println("join4" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}

//MARK: instead of an explicit external name
// You can opt out of this behavior by writing an underscore (_) instead of an explicit external name when you define the parameter. However, external names for parameters with default values are preferred.

func join5(s1: String, _ s2: String, _ joiner: String = " ") -> String {
    println("join5" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}

//MARK: Shorthand External Parameter Names
// Provide an external parameter name with the same local parameter name
// Swift provides an automatic external name for any parameter that has a default value. The automatic external name is the same as the local name, as if you had written a hash symbol before the local name in your code.

func join6(#s1: String, s2: String, joiner: String = " ") -> String {
    println("join6" + s1 + joiner + s2)
    return s1 + joiner + s2
}
```

And you can see how to use them

```
join1("s1", s2: "s2", joiner: "-")

join2(string: "s1", toString: "s2", withJoiner: "-")

join3(string: "s1", toString: "s2", withJoiner: "-")
join3(string: "s1", toString: "s2")

join4("s1", s2: "s2", joiner: "-")
join4("s1", s2: "s2")

join5("s1", "s2", "-")
join5("s1", "s2")

join6(s1: "s1", s2: "s2", joiner: "-")
join6(s1: "s1", s2: "s2")
```

Answer (score -1):

From the Swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234):

> Function parameters can have both a local name (for use within the
>   function’s body) and an external name (for use when calling the
>   function), as described in External Parameter Names. The same is true
>   for method parameters, because methods are just functions that are
>   associated with a type. However, **the default behavior of local names
>   and external names is different for functions and methods.**
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Specifically, Swift [makes] the first parameter name in a method a local
>   parameter name by default, and [makes] the second and subsequent
>   parameter names both local and external parameter names by default.
>   This convention matches the typical naming and calling convention you
>   will be familiar with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for
>   expressive method calls without the need to qualify your parameter
>   names.
>
> Consider this alternative version of the Counter class...
>
> ```
> class Counter {
>     var count: Int = 0
>     func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) {
>         count += amount * numberOfTimes
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This **incrementBy(_:numberOfTimes:)** method has two parameters—amount
>   and numberOfTimes. By default, Swift treats amount as a local name
>   only, but treats numberOfTimes as both a local and an external name.
>   You call the method as follows:
>
> ```
> let counter = Counter()
> counter.incrementBy(5, numberOfTimes: 3)
> // counter value is now 15
> ```
>
> You don’t need to define an external parameter name for the first
>   argument value, because its purpose is clear from the function name
>   incrementBy. The second argument, however, is qualified by an external
>   parameter name to make its purpose clear when the method is called.
>
> This default behavior effectively treats the method as if you had
>   written a hash symbol (#) before the numberOfTimes parameter:
>
> ```
> func incrementBy(amount: Int, #numberOfTimes: Int) {
>     count += amount * numberOfTimes
> }
> ```
>
> The default behavior described above means that method definitions in
>   Swift are written with the same grammatical style as Objective-C, and
>   are called in a natural, expressive way.

So, to nullify the external name of the second parameter of a method you can explicitly write '_' for the external name:

> ```
> class Counter {
>     var count: Int = 0
>     func incrementBy(amount: Int, _ numberOfTimes: Int) {
>         count += amount * numberOfTimes
>     }
> }
> ```

Now the syntax for the method name becomes:

> **incrementBy(__:__:)**

The syntax tells you how to call the method.  In this case, the syntax tells you that there are two un-named method arguments, so you call the method like this:

```
 incrementBy(3, 2)
```

If the method name is `incrementBy(_:numberOfTimes:)`, the syntax tells you that the first argument is un-named while the second argument's name is numberOfTimes, so you call the method like this:

```
 incrementBy(3, numberOfTimes:2)
```