# method isn't overriding any function from superclass (override func collectionView)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keyboard, uicollectionview

Trying to register a tap on the collection view to dismiss the keyboard using the following

```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    inputTextField.endEditing(true)

}
```

however I'm getting a compile error saying that the method doesn't override any method from it's superclass.

The class is of type UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Also using swift 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a Swift 3 function - you want the updated version of that - you can tell because its first parameter doesn't have a `_` in front. The one you actually want is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  }
```

Use that one instead and everything should work.

Comment: It is not easy for me to discover this issue, haha.

Comment: @chengsam It bit me really, really hard when converting a large project from Swift 2 -> 3

Comment: I've been learning swift for a while and just got around to updating to swift 3. Btw, solution works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sschale, could you explain what this underscore is? I'm completely new to Swift and I haven't done any UI development in a long time. This construct is confusing me; are these callbacks on the CollectionView class, or are we overriding method overloads on the base class?

Comment: For anyone swinging by here, I answered my own question with 1 Google search (yeah, I know): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627106/why-do-i-need-underscores-in-swift

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `override` keyword.

Comment: Removing the override removes the error but doesn't register the tap on the collection view.

Comment: Did you class implements `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`? And make sure your collectionView has set the delegate.

Comment: I used sizeForItemAtIndexPath perfectly fine so I know UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is implemented and the delegate is set. Is there new syntax for didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: sschale's answer should be your solution.