# How do I interpret a Swift function declaration?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, syntax

I have questions about this statement:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

`internal` is the scope?

`func` is a keyword that declares method/functions?

`tableView` is the name of the method?

What is `_tableView`? Is this the name of a parameter? If so, why do we need the underscore when `cellForRowAt` does not have an underscore, assuming `cellForRowAt` is also a name?

Is `UITableView` a parameter type?

Is `IndexPath` a parameter type?

What is `indexPath` in `cellForRowAt indexPath`? Why are there 2 words?

`UITableViewCell` is the return type, right?

So confused, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Nothing really wrong with this question, but if you're having trouble with the language at this level you'd do well to seek out more introductory material, like [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/).

Comment: Please read the [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) chapter of the Swift book (and the rest of the book too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `internal` is the scope?

This is an access modifier. It means that only code in the same module can see/call this symbol.

`internal` is implicit if you leave it off, and has meaning primarily for when you're making frameworks — an app that links a framework can see only the framework's `public` symbols, but code within the framework can see other `internal` symbols in the framework. (And code in one type within the framework can't see `private` symbols inside another type.)

> `func` is a keyword that declares method/functions?

Yes. In Swift, a "method" is just a `func`tion declared in the scope of a type (class, struct, protocol, enum).

> `tableView` is the name of the method?

Yes... in one sense. It's what is often called the "base name" of a function/method — the part before the open-parenthesis `(`. The full name of the method, which people use when trying to unambiguously refer to this method versus others, includes all the argument labels: `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. (Even a full name isn't unambiguous in Swift, though, because functions/methods can be overloaded on parameter/return types.)

Usually a function name is a verb phrase, describing the action performed by a function or characterizing the result, but there's a longstanding convention otherwise in delegate/datasource protocols. (And this method is from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.) In such protocols, the "base name" of the function to name the object that's delegating some action.

> What is `_tableView`? Is this the name of a parameter? If so, why do we need the underscore when `cellForRowAt` does not have an underscore, assuming `cellForRowAt` is also a name?

It's not `_tableView`, it's `_ tableView` — note the space. [The underscore generally means "ignore this" in Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39627305/957768) In this case, the underscore takes the place of an *argument label*, meaning that the caller of this method doesn't write one for the first parameter:

```
let cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: selectedIndexPath)
                    ^ nothing here, just the value being passed as an argument
```

> Is `UITableView` a parameter type?
>   Is `IndexPath` a parameter type?

Yes.

> What is `indexPath` in `cellForRowAt indexPath`? Why are there 2 words?

`cellForRowAt` is an *argument label*. `indexPath` is the internal (to your implementation) name of the parameter.

Argument labels are used by whoever calls your function — e.g. a call site for this looks like:

```
let cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: selectedIndexPath)
```

Parameter names are how you refer to that value within the function body:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    self.doSomethingWithCellData(indexPath)
    ...
}
```

> `UITableViewCell` is the return type, right?

Right. If you don't include a `return` statement in your implementation of this method, or `return` anything that isn't a `UITableViewCell`, the compiler gets upset.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. The name of the function is not `tableView`. The name of the function is `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: As a certain Bard [once implied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet), "name" is a fluid concept. :) Edited to clarify base name vs full name.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about `internal` and `func` and `tableView`. The underscore is there because you do not have to include the parameter name when calling the function. You can do:

```
tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: someIndexPath)
```

Instead of:

```
tableView(tableView: myTableView, cellForRowAt: someIndexPath)
```

`UITableView` is the parameter type same with `IndexPath`. When the function is called (as I showed above) you use the first word `cellForRowAt` however internally the function will use `indexPath`. The two words are there for readability when the function is called. `UITableViewCell` is the return type.

Comment: All true, though "you" (typically) never call this function, you just implement it. In delegate protocols, UIKit calls you!

Comment: That is a good clarification point @rickster

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. The name of the function is not `tableView`. The name of the function is `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.