# In what situation, should I use _ as a parameter in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift3, uitextfielddelegate

I am new to apple Swift.I am trying to build a demo app based on this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1). I have found that the app is not working. After several trial and fails, I have found that if I change the line of code:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
```

to

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
```

I am able to run the code properly.

I want to know what happens by adding the _ as one of the arguments. Both of the two methods will not result in compilation errors. But the first one does give warnings like:

```
ViewController.swift:35:10: Instance method 'textFieldDidEndEditing(textField:)' 
nearly matches optional requirement 'textFieldDidEndEditing' of protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'
```

Since the first one is given by apple tutorial, I am not sure whether it is a mistake. Can somebody clarify my doubts?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Xcode

Comment: You can have the correct answer here: [What's the _ underscore representative of in Swift References?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437388/whats-the-underscore-representative-of-in-swift-references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Swift 3.0. The tutorial you are following might be a Swift 2.2 or Swift 2.3 version. It is nothing but a Syntax change from what I have observed. Even I faced this situation yesterday when I have updated to Xcode 8.0

Answer (score 1):

From Swift 3 First argument labels are also the standard for initializers.

**Swift 3 Evolution**

> First parameter declarations will match the existing behavior of the second and later parameters. All parameters, regardless of position, will behave uniformly. This will create a simple, consistent approach to parameter declaration throughout the Swift programming language and bring method and function declarations in-sync with initializers, which already use this standard.

For example

```
func foo(x: Int, y: Int)
```

will declare `foo(x:y:)` and not `foo(_:,y:)`.

The existing external label overrides will continue to apply to first parameters. You establish external parameter names before the local parameter name it supports, separated by a space. For example,

```
func foo(xx x: Int, yy y: Int) //declares foo(xx:yy:) and

func foo(_ x: Int, y: Int) //explicitly declares foo(_:y:)
```

Read more about first parameter in [SE-0046](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple parameters with no external name, you must use the ” _ ” underscore character as its external name: