# Creates a string containing the given character issue

Tags: swift3

In the Apple Documentation :

```
init(_: Character)
Creates a string containing the given character.

c: The character to convert to a string.

Declaration
init(_ c: Character)
```

I try to create a string with a character using  string init but I fail.I don't understand the declaration above.I want to create a string including "k".

Here is example:

```
String(_ c: "k") // fails
String("k" c: Character) // fails
```

What is the correct way acoording to declaration above.I don't understand what  _: means in the declaration.

Can someone explain what the declaration means in human language ?

Comment: Have a look at [What's the _ underscore representative of in Swift References?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437388/whats-the-underscore-representative-of-in-swift-references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
init(_: Character)
     ^
```

means the parameter doesn't have an external name. So when you call that initializer you simply put the value, without a label.

Like this

```
let char: Character = "A"
let word = String(char)
```

Comment: so init(_ c: Character) means c is of character type and you can input c directly into init without paramater name ? c is any character.

Comment: It means you __must__ input `c` without a param name.