# Expression type '(_) -> _ ' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

getting error while upgrading from swift 3 to swift 4. the error comes when using UICollection performBatchUpdates() method. My code looks something like this,

```
Class A: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func someMethod() {
         collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] _ in // error:  Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context
             self?.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
            }, completion: nil)
         })
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the underscore `_ in` to `in`

Answer (score 1):

`_ in` means:

1. Acknowledging the existence of a variable being passed to you *in* to the closure.
2. Yet you want to ignore that variable ie not allocate any memory. You ignore it by not giving the variable a name. See
   [What's the _ underscore representative of in Swift
   References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437388/whats-the-underscore-representative-of-in-swift-references).

If a variable is not being passed from `performBatchUpdates` then
    that acknowledgement becomes unnecessary and incorrect. So you have to remove `_`. But still keep `in` because you need to pass *in* a `weak` reference to `self` to avoid memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

remove "_" in

```
//...
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] _ in
//...
```

make it

```
//...
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code won't compile as class should has a `NSObject` descendant   in addition that `performBatchUpdates` has no variables in it's completion so this `_` should be removed

```
class A : UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

        func someMethod() {
            collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self]  in
                self?.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
          })
        }
}
```