# How do I refer to a variable in a function?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How would I call the sun object I have made in a function (hello) from another function (collide)?

```
func collide() {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, **sun.frame**)) {
            [EndGame];
        }

 func hello() {
        let sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
}
```

Comment: You can't since the `sun` variable only lives within the scope of the `hello()` function. You might want to make the `sun` variable a class variable

Comment: make sun into a class variable

Comment: Did you mean to _return_ the sun sprite from `hello`?

Comment: How do I make it into a class variable? @KaanDedeoglu

Comment: @RayToal I tried it having 'hello' return sun sprite but then i got a "missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call"

Comment: Probably a function/method confusion. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050844/swift-missing-argument-label-xxx-in-call).

Answer (score 4):

You can't - the `sun` variable is local to the `hello` function, and it doesn't exist outside its scope.

If `collide` is invoked from `hello`, you can just pass it as an argument:

```
func collide(sun: SKSpriteNode) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, sun.frame)) {
        [EndGame];
    }
}

func hello() {
    let sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
    ...
    collide(sun)
}
```

Otherwise if, as I think, these are instance methods of a class, just turn the `sun` variable into an instance property:

```
class Test {
    private var sun: SKSpriteNode?

    func collide(sun: SKSpriteNode) {
        if let sun = self.sun {
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, sun.frame)) {
                [EndGame];
            }
        }
    }

    func hello() {
        self.sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Antonio's answer, you can search an `SKNode's children` using a unique name.

For example.

```
let sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Sun")
sun.name = "sun"
self.addChild(sun)
```

You can get it back by

```
if let sun =  self.childNodeWithName("sun")
{
    //use sun here
}
```

`childNodeWithName` returns an optional `SKNode?`.