# parameters' label in a function

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning **swift**, in apple's tutorial, it has the following code snippet when introducing `function`:

```
func greet(name: String, lunch: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(name), eat \(lunch)."
}
//Why here 'lunch' cannot be removed? 
greet("Bob", lunch: "Tuesday")
```

The code defined an `greet(String, String)` function, but when it calls the function:

```
greet("Bob", lunch: "Tuesday")
```

the 1st parameter doesn't have label 'name', but the 2nd one has label 'lunch', if I remove label 'lunch', compiler error says "**Missing argument label `lunch` in call**"

Why the 1st parameter could be without label, but not the 2nd one?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045890/why-does-a-function-call-require-the-parameter-name-in-swift

Comment: [Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) and scroll down to Function Parameter Names.

Answer (score 1):

#### Clarity

The main reason is clarity.

In Swift's function naming style, the method name usually implies something about the first argument, but not later arguments.

For example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doSomething", name: UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

`self` is implied by the syntax to be the observer you're adding to the notification center.

`greet("Bob", "Tuesday")` would imply that Bob is being greeted, but doesn't tell you anything about what Tuesday has to do with things. This makes code less readable, so it isn't allowed.

#### Default Parameter Values

A second reason is default parameter values. Consider instead this function:

```
func greetForLunch(name: String, food: String = "pasta", restaurant: String = "Olive Garden") -> String {
    return "Hello \(name). Would you like to eat \(food) at \(restaurant)?"
}
```

Since the two latter arguments have default values, you can omit one or both of them, for example:

```
greetForLunch("Bob", food: "endless breadsticks")
// "Hello Bob. Would you like to eat endless breadsticks at Olive Garden?"
```

But if you didn't specify `food` here, like so:

```
greetForLunch("Bob", "endless breadsticks")
```

It would be ambiguous about whether the second argument should be assigned to `food` or `restaurant`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift functions can specify local and external argument names:

```
func greet(who name: String = "world") {
    println("hello \(name)")
}

// prints "hello world"
greet()

// prints "hello jeff"
greet(who:"jeff")

// error
greet("jeff")

// error
greet(name: "jeff")
```

To opt out of this behavior you can use an underscore for the external name. Note that the first parameter implicitly uses the "no external name" behavior:

```
func greet(name: String = "world", _ hello: String = "hello") {
    println("\(hello) \(name)")
}

// prints "hello world"
greet()

// prints "hello jeff"
greet("jeff")

// prints "hi jeff"
greet("jeff", "hi")

// error
greet(name: "jeff")
```

You can use the # prefix to use the same local and external name for the first parameter:

```
func greet(#name: String = "world", hello: String = "hello") {
    println("\(hello) \(name)")
}

// prints "hi jeff"
greet(name: "jeff", hello: "hi")
```

Taken from [Swift error: missing argument label 'name:' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049272/swift-error-missing-argument-label-name-in-call)

Comment: Worth noting that the `#` syntax had been removed from Swift as of Swift 2.0. To accomplish this in Swift 2.0, you'd use `func greet(name name: String = …`